# remove all empty values from url string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to remove all empty params from a url string. My url looks like this

`http://localhost/wm/frontend/www/?test=&lol=1&boo=2`

my code should return

`http://localhost/wm/frontend/www/?lol=1&boo=2`

but it doesn't instead it returns

`http://localhost/wm/frontend/www/?&lol=1&boo=2`

This is the regex i'm using `replace("/(&?\w+=((?=$)|(?=&)))/g","")` i know i could just use `replace()` strings that match '?&' after the 1st replace, but i would rather edit my regex to do so, so it's in 1 line of code. Any ideas?

here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcfcx0bj/)

Comment: Just wondering, why you need to remove it client side and not instead handle it server side?  BTW, how these URLs are in first place build?

Comment: @A.Wolff for a filtered search using history.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex for replacement:

```
/[^?&=]+=(?:&|$)|&[^?&=]+=(?=&|$)/g
```

And replace it by:

```
""
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dM4yS5/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can for example say:

```
var s = 'http://localhost/wm/frontend/www/?test=&lol=1&boo=2&r=';
s = s.replace(/\w*=\&/g, '');
s = s.replace(/&\w*=$/g, '');
```

That is, remove a block of `letters` + `=` + `&`. Then, remove `&` + `letters` + `=` at the end of the line (indicated by `$`).

For your input, it returns:

```
http://localhost/wm/frontend/www/?lol=1&boo=2
```

See it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hx965fk5/1/) or directly here:

```js
var s = 'http://localhost/wm/frontend/www/?test=&lol=1&boo=2&r=';
s = s.replace(/\w*=\&/g, '');
s = s.replace(/&\w*=$/g, '');
document.write(s)
```

#### Test

If the input contains blocks in the middle and in the end:

```
http://localhost/wm/frontend/www/?test=&lol=1&boo=2&r=
```

the code I wrote above returns:

```
http://localhost/wm/frontend/www/?lol=1&boo=2
```

Comment: This would not remove trailing `&x=`

Comment: True, thanks @AlexK. I just updated covering this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/\w+=&|&\w+=$/g,
```

```js
var url = "http://localhost/wm/frontend/www/?test=&lol=1&boo=2&j=";
document.write(url.replace(/\w+=&|&\w+=$/g, ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to invoke native's 'replace', which could be used with a regex in its first argument.

```
str.replace(regex, replace_str)
```

Please, see this fiddle to see a running example: http://jsfiddle.net/xvqasgmu/1/